# How to Trim down a Colum in a dataframe when it exceeds a certain amount of characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I I'm trying to trim down a column down when it exceeds over 40 column but I'm unsure how to do it.

I have been reading the string.lstrip() method but it looks like its only for white spaces?

Example data:

| FirstLineofAddress |
| --- |
| 00 TheDeathstaristheonlyhomeinthegalaxyformeandmysonlukeskywalker |
| 01 Alderaanusedtobemyhomeuntillmofftarkinhadhiswaywithitthatmassiveninny |
| 02 Makekashyyykgreatagain |

How would i trim that down to not exceed 40 characters?

I saw this on stackoverflow but not sure how to use it in practice?

```
info = (data[:40] + '..') if len(data) > 40 else data
```

Comment: `pandas.Series.str` implements many vectorized string operations - meaning the operation is applied to each value in the series. So, `data["FirstLineofAddress"] = data["FirstLineofAddress"].str[:40]`. If you want to do all of the columns, you need to loop column by column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you just need to use `.str`:

- Access the string in the column using `.str`
- Slice the first 40 characters  using `[:40]`

```
>>> df["FirstLineofAddress"].str[:40]

0    00 TheDeathstaristheonlyhomeinthegalaxyf
1    01 Alderaanusedtobemyhomeuntillmofftarki
2                   02 Makekashyyykgreatagain
```